# Should flagged low quality posts that are “wrong” be recommended for deletion?

Tags: discussion, support, review

Please close if this is a cross-post, but since each community will handle their review queues independently (and therefore differently) I believe the scope is different enough for multiple questions.

Based on the example in this question: [Should flagged low quality posts that are "wrong" be recommended for deletion?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5136/should-flagged-low-quality-posts-that-are-wrong-be-recommended-for-deletion)

How should answers that a reviewer believes to be valid, but factually incorrect in the StackOverflow review queue be handled?

Recommend for deletion with a custom comment?
Looks good but with a downvote?
Some other action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not delete content just for being wrong.  You should downvote it, and optionally add a comment indicating what is wrong (and possibly how it could be fixed).  If there are competing answers that are correct you can upvote them.  If there are no competing answers, or none of them are good enough, you could consider posting your own answer to correctly solve the problem.  You could, if you want, mention the other answers and why those other solutions are incorrect (as long as you still provide an actual answer in addition to addressing other answers).

Answer (score 3):

Answers that are wrong should not be deleted, except (maybe) in the case they are suggesting something very dangerous to be done. (I am thinking of a DIY question for which the answer would suggest something very dangerous for the safety.)

If an answer is wrong, it should be down-voted.